# Developer Edition & Summer 16?

Tags: configuration

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to access the Summer 16 preview within a Developer Edition Org?

Answer (score 5):

You can sign up for  a [pre-release version](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring16-45632967.jsp) of the Summer 16 org .

To roll out Summer 16 in your developer org as per [trust site](https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/calendar) it will be released on 12th of June .